# Purpose of IP address under Setup -> Networking -> Port Setup in DD-WRT web interface

Tags: dd-wrt

In the web interface of the DD-WRT firmware (v24-sp2 mega - build 14896) under Setup -> Networking -> Port Setup there are fields for an IP address and a subnet mask. They appear at the bottom of that section, after the options for multicast forwarding and Masquerade / NAT. The following is a [link to a screenshot showing the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACZLs.png).

The DD-WRT help page for this page does not state anything about these fields. What is their purpose and which IP address and subnet mask should be entered there in most cases (i.e., in a standard configuration)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, those IP address and subnet mask fields appear because of a bug in the DD-WRT firmware web interface. The following is a [link to the SVN ticket for the bug](http://svn.dd-wrt.com/ticket/1853).

The most important parts of the description at the time of writing this answer are the following.

> [...]
>
> Normally all the settings for a manually created bridge are in the 'Create Bridge' section. On Broadcom k2.6 builds a duplicate set of settings appear in the 'Port Setup' section after you have filled out all of the bridge settings in the 'Create Bridge' section. Once this duplicate set of settings shows up, configuring the bridge becomes very troublesome.[...]
>
> To reproduce this go to the Networking page on a Broadcom k2.6 build, add a bridge, give the bridge a name, Apply the page, optionally fill out the IP/netmask for the bridge (0.0.0.0/0 is fine though), and Apply the page again.

To apply a new IP address and subnet mask, one has to use the IP address and subnet mask fields under `Port Setup`, not under `Bridging`.